# my firebase only works when I run the page in visual studio

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

im making a website with firebase (users, database), it worked perfectly couple day ago but now when I opened the main page from the file explorer the firebase didn't worked but when I opened it from visual studio it worked like a magic. I also got two weird errors:

```
On {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}
code
:
"auth/network-request-failed"
message
:
"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
__proto__
:
Error
```

```
main.html:1 Failed to load https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyBqJx6CHQdHf2VibQTVPGb1NJ7oiCumK3c: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have no idea what the problem is soI would appreciate any help or attempt to help

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't install firebase CLI. install then run at root of your projec as firebase serve. And your project will be served at port 5000, so http://localhost:5000/ will serve your project with full features of firebase. For full info : [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/)